# XML driven Venn Diagrams for Flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript-2, visualization, data-visualization

Is anyone aware of a Venn diagram library for Flash?  XML driven would be preferred.

Other non-compiled solutions welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not Flash Google Charts does offer this cool API:

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/gallery/venn_charts.html